# Ruby: End of file reached with gem serialport

Tags: ruby, serial-port, eoferror

Using gem serialport in ruby i'm having the error code `EOFError: end of file reached`

```
irb
2.0.0-p451 :001 > require 'serialport'
 => true 
2.0.0-p451 :002 > serial_port = SerialPort.new "/dev/ttyUSB0", 115200
 => #<SerialPort:fd 7> 
2.0.0-p451 :009 > serial_port.write "@00RD0000020054*\r"
 => 17 
2.0.0-p451 :010 > r = serial_port.readline("\r")
EOFError: end of file reached
    from (irb):10:in `readline'
    from (irb):10
    from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Try crate separate SerialPort objects for reading and writing. It seems to be an issue with Ruby - see here: http://www.rngtng.com/2009/11/27/if-your-ruby-serial-port-doesnt-read-what-youre-sending/

Answer (score 0):

Attempt the following

```
serial_port.readlines
```

Instead of the

```
serial_port.readline("\r")
```

I might also suggest

```
serial_port.readlines("\r")
```